# What is the "comfortable" acceleration in a curve and braking in a car?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, everyday-life, biology

A car that makes a curve or a braking will naturally have its horizontal G-Force altered according to its speed and the intensity of the braking or the angle of the curve.

My question is: which acceleration / G-Force could be considered comfortable, especially for passengers?

When I say "comfortable" I mean a normal day-to-day driving, like a mother taking her children to school ...

Comment: Just FYI, while this is an interesting question, it's like to be voted as off-topic since it's more about what humans like as opposed to something intrinsically about physics. That said, I think a truly good answer would explain *why* the preferred acceleration curve is the way it is by linking the human experience to something physical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about human behavior, not physics.

Comment: The question is due to a new car simulation that needs to reflect a real-world condition on a human body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia's article [on the order of magnitude of the g-force for various activities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force#Typical_examples), unless you find roller coasters comfortable, the maximum comfortable acceleration is between $1.55g$ and $2.55g$.

Comment: Thanks. Just a beginner question: Is horizontal gravity (the stationary car) 1g or 0g?

Comment: @RogérioDec stationary car is 1g. You'd need a vector sum for other accelerations.